# how do you trigger a function when more content is loaded onto a page, like tumblr and infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hi I'm writing a google chrome extension that redesigns tumblr for a project,

I'm trying to get rid of the 'notes' after the number of notes.

So far I have used this, except tumblr loads more posts as you scroll down and those don't get affected... :/

How would I trigger this function everytime more posts get loaded, or another way?

```
$('.note_link_current').each( function(index) {
  // Inside this function, "this" refers to the (DOM) element selected
  var text = $(this).text();
  /* ... */
});
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to run some piece of code over every node inserted into DOM filtered by class.

The modern way to do so is with DOM MutationObserver. Here's a [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/934239) about it, and here's [good documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on it.

In a nutshell, here's what you should do:

```
function handleNote(element){
  var text = $(element).text();
  /* ... */
}

// Initial replacement
$('.note_link_current').each( function(index) { handleNote(this); });

var observer = new MutationObserver( function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach( function (mutation) {
    // Here, added nodes for each mutation event are in mutation.addedNodes
    $(mutation.addedNodes).filter('.note_link_current').each(
      function(index) { handleNote(this); }
    );
  });
});

// Watch for all subtree modifications to catch new nodes
observer.observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me :/ I get mutations alerts as i scroll but not just when new things are loaded...